# powershell exchange shared mailboxes per user

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Does anyone of the powershell scripts for finding out what single user has access to what shared mailboxes, via doing it via powershell

Comment: I'm confused by the wording of your question, but I think you want to find every mailbox that a user has access to. If so, you need to get all the mailboxes, get the Acl on the mailbox, and then check to see if one of the Aces has the user listed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Mailboxes = Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails SharedMailbox -ResultSize:Unlimited | Select Identity,Alias,DisplayName | sort displayname
$Mailboxes | sort displayname | foreach {Get-MailboxPermission -Identity $_.alias | ft identity,user,accessrights} > C:\Temp\SharedPermissions.txt
```

Source: https://www.msazureteam.com/?p=500